# Toast Item selected - AdapterView/ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onclicklistener, android-adapterview

I have created an Adapter arraylist that uses a LayoutInflater so images keep ratio. I am trying to perform a simple toast of the item title selected i.e "Beef".
Everthing workd as expected except I am getting an output from toast of, example

> test com.sweatboxbbq.www.sweatboxbbq.Kansas City$MyAdaptor$Item@42aa9398

I know I am requesting a string value of and I'm getting it, but from the code, I can't figure out how to get what I want.
I want to capture the title only so I can toast it back (for now then aventually do something else).

Example `items.add(new Item( beef, R.drawable.mine_beef));` I would get a string value of "beef"

Maybe I can id the title's of these array items somehow and pull them from there with the onclick method?

below is my Java code

```
public class KansasCity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kansas_city);

    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.meat_choice);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));


    //on click starts here
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> MyAdapter, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            String flavorPicked = "" +
                    String.valueOf(MyAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(KansasCity.this, "Test " + flavorPicked,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


//gridview
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item( "Beef", R.drawable.mine_beef));
        items.add(new Item("Chicken", R.drawable.mine_chicken));
        items.add(new Item("Swine", R.drawable.mine_pork));
        items.add(new Item("Fish", R.drawable.mine_pork));
        items.add(new Item("Turkey", R.drawable.mine_pork));
        items.add(new Item("Sauce", R.drawable.mine_pork));

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item) getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;


    }

    private class Item {
        final String name;
        final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }



    }


}

   }
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either override `toString()` in your `Item` class and make it return the String you want to display, or make the member `name` of `Item`  public, and use it like

```
String flavorPicked = ((Item)MyAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)).name;
```

Comment: Thanks man! Your a life saver! I changed the code to `String flavorPicked = ((KansasCity.MyAdapter.Item)MyAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)).name;`
and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the " after flavorPicked

Toast.makeText(KansasCity.this, "Test " + flavorPicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: That was my fault, a typo when posting, I corrected my code to reflect my issue.